# How can I truncate a string using bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have some strings like that

`example-dot-com
hello-world-exam-ple`

I'd want to get

`example-d-c
hello-w-e-p`

Thanks

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You *can* use `sed` or maybe `perl` to do it but I really recommend you write a separate script to do this and use that in your shell program or outright shift to another language. This kind of thing will, very soon, give you an unmaintainable nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `sed` in this way:

```
sed 's/\(-.\)[^-]*/\1/g' your_file
```

Answer (score 1):

For `awk` solution,

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="-"} {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)$i=substr($i,1,1)}1' file
```